# Given a person's age in years, what is the best way to estimate their age correctly in the future?

Tags: probability

I have a database of people who have only given their age in years (and the date that they specified it). Because I want to keep this number accurate over time, I want to convert ages to birth years.

What is the best way to compute a birth date that will maximize the probability that on any given day, a user's age (calculated from the "birth date" that I make up) will be accurate?

Here's a example of the data I have available:

```
 age | date_provided
-----+------------
  21 | 2014-03-22 15:14:50.431278-05
  31 | 2014-04-21 18:11:27.299024-05
  27 | 2014-03-23 22:35:16.81655-05
  25 | 2014-03-12 09:27:15.865215-05
  30 | 2013-09-01 19:16:17.146388-05
  37 | 2014-01-17 10:50:49.393871-06
  26 | 2014-03-26 18:04:23.520413-05
  30 | 2014-04-11 10:05:35.585068-05
  30 | 2013-07-08 21:14:03.876834-05
  26 | 2014-06-05 15:15:50.63014-05
  16 | 2014-02-26 15:45:23.98677-06
  26 | 2013-11-05 19:55:05.163587-06
  18 | 2014-03-16 16:10:40.481958-05
  29 | 2014-06-23 20:18:28.884308-05
  21 | 2014-06-15 01:04:24.83778-05
  30 | 2014-02-15 02:52:52.147953-06
  27 | 2013-12-27 21:33:28.819328-06
  31 | 2014-05-24 09:39:52.774244-05
  28 | 2014-02-18 19:56:22.064-06
  29 | 2014-01-25 16:03:23.894607-06
  29 | 2014-02-12 13:10:36.682297-06
  28 | 2014-01-16 08:32:38.51522-06
```

One option is to set their birthdate to `date_provided - age`, but that assumes that their birthday was the day they gave their age. One could also set all of their birthdays to the same day, but then it's likely that everyone's age will be wrong at least half of the year.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: For the sake of this question, assume that the ages provided are accurate.

Comment: maybe normally distribute the age around date_provided - age -365/2

Comment: ooff, actually my idea is weird. uniform distribution would be better I think.

Comment: You are assuming that people know their age and tell the truth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can minimize the error (assuming the data you are given is accurate!?!) by setting birth date=date provided-age-$\frac 12$ year.  That will be within $\frac 12$ year at all times.  You are assuming a uniform distribution of age as [age provided,age provided+1) and taking the middle.